# Vector of double to a vector bytes

Tags: c++, c++11, vector

I have a `std::vector<double>` and need to work with a library the takes a `const vector<uint8_t>`. I specify what type the data is to the library with an enum.

Is there anyway that I can avoid copying data completely and have the byte vector internally refer to the same data as the double vector? Since the byte vector is const and the double vector won't change during the lifetime of the byte vector, this appears like it would be pretty safe. There is a lot of data so copying it really isn't an option.

Comment: If the library only takes that exact type then no, you would have to copy. If it accepts a template parameter then you have some leeway to implement a wrapper.

Comment: "[...] need to work with a library the takes a const vector<uint32_t>. I specify what type the data is to the library with an enum." If it takes `vector<std::uint32_t>` why would you have to specify that? A template would be much better.

Comment: Oops I made a typo. Its actually uint8_t.

Comment: This is why libraries should accept iterator pairs, and NOT enforce choice of a particular container on the user.

Answer (score 1):

If your "byte vector" were actually a vector of bytes then you would have a chance, because you can legally examine pretty much anything as a `char` array. However, `uint32_t`s are not bytes and they are certainly not `char`s. So, no, you basically can't do this without horrible hacky magic whose safety will be entirely implementation dependent.

*Either way*, you can't do it with the vector types: you'd have to cast and pass the result of `std::vector::data()`, i.e. a pointer.

Sorry but I have to recommend revisiting your design. If the library you're using *really* takes a vector of integers that is actually supposed to be a vector of doubles, then its developers have put you in an awkward position.

Comment: It is of type uint8_t not 32. My mistake.